# Where can i find dll for linked server in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, linked-server

Actually I am new to this. I am trying to create a ppt. so for the components part for the dll there put this dll. I was surprised how to find out this thing,

Comment: Nope, I've tried reading this several times, and still have no idea what you're trying to do. Try not to use abbreviations (what's a ppt?). Try to explain what your problem is, what you've tried so far, where you've looked for solutions.

Comment: I'm with Damien_The_Unbeliever on this one, I really cannot understand what you are asking. Also what has a PowerPoint presentation (ppt) got to do with it?